# ActiveAdmin: How to remove `[ ] (Toggle Selection)` for grid index renderer?

Tags: activeadmin

This is what it looks like:

[image: Toggle Selection checkbox]

I don't need it in my AA app, how to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is rather simple.

Just add `batch_actions` as false to your model register like so:

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  config.batch_actions = false
end
```